# Number greater than 255 in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell

How to return a number greater than 255 in

```
function returnnumber(){
    x=256
    return $x
}

returnnumber
echo "value: $?"
```

I wanted to type 256 and 256 return

But 256 return 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In bash, `return` does not do what you expect it does from other programming languages:

> The **return** value of a simple command is its exit status, or 128+*n* if
>   the command is terminated by signal *n*.

This code will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

function returnnumber(){
    echo $1
}

returnnumber 256
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't! Shell functions don't really *return* anything, they just exit with an exit status, like other UNIX commands. And like other UNIX commands, their [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Unix) must be an unsigned byte.

If you want to store the output of a command (which includes functions), you can capture its standard output in the usual way.

```
d() {
    echo 'hi'
}
x=$(d)
echo "$x"
hi
```

Here's [Wooledge's wiki on getting values from commands](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002).